# How to route a string in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

I have a controller in my ASP.NET Webb app that should display search results when I search like this..

```
Cases/Search/Volvo
```

In this case `Volvo` is the string that I searched for.

It currently work when searching like this..

```
Cases/Search?q=volvo
```

How should my routing look like for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using [Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing) routing

```
[Route("[controller]"]
public class CasesController : Controller {

    //Matches GET cases/search/volvo
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search/{q}")]
    public IActionResult Search(string q) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: If you want one line less, you can use `[HttpGet("search/{q]")]` :)